# Disttribution of magnitude of gaussian

Tags: probability

Can anyone guide on how two get distribution of the magnitude of complex gaussian random variable

i.e find the distribution of $$|X|$$ where $$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the [folded normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution), or in the case where X has zero mean, it's the [half-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).

Comment: thanks. when is the distibution Rayleigh then? do you have an idea?

Comment: Never. The Rayleigh distribution is similar to the half-normal, but it's what you get when you take the geometric mean of two iid normal variables. If you look at the Wikipedia articles for the two, notice how the half-normal pdf for positive values is just a scaled normal distribution, while the Rayleigh pdf has an "x" factor out front instead.